# Magento how to get current currency code in outer file

Tags: magento

My website has 4 currency in one store. I am not able to get current currency code in the file of root directory using below code.

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

This code working to any inner file but not working in the root file. In root file it always gives default currency code but I want current currency code.

Please help.

Comment: Please add full code of your external file

Comment: Thank you for very quick response. Here is full code.

Comment: <?php 
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   require_once ('app/Mage.php'); 
   umask(0); 
   Mage::app(); 
   $codes = Mage::app()->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(true);
   foreach ($codes as $code) {
        echo $code;
   }
```

**Try**

Try with this code. Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks Nirav, but I want only current currency not all. This code gives all currency code.

Comment: I have only one store and there are 4 currencies. I have currency switcher on my website for switch between currency. So, for example, my default currency of store is USD and when I switched currency switcher to CAD at that time all price changed to CAD with CAD currency symbol but this root file currency doesn't change and remain to default currency USD. In short, i want current currency in root file.